# Solid angle: Must a region subtending a solid angle be (simply) connected?

Tags: geometry, solid-angle

Although answers to [the question "What is a Solid Angle?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624833/what-is-a-solid-angle) explain that the shape of the area subtending a solid angle doesn't matter, my question is if the region has to be simply connected (no holes). For example, is the following shape (shaded area) allowed? And, can there be multiple unconnected areas all contributing to a solid angle?

[image]

Comment: Why not? (note: I'm serious)

Comment: @achillehui So far everywhere I've read something about solid angle, the shape of the area is depicted as circular (which is oddly specific). That's why I am unsure. (Also, in 2d, there is no analog of the subtending arc having different shapes.)